# Laravel foreign key onDelete('cascade') not working

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I have a many-to-many relationship between User & Role, with a role_user table. My migrations are setup as so (simplified):

`users` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
    });
}
```

`roles` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

`role_user` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

So as per the docs, I set my foreign keys to unsigned.

Now, I add a couple of users, and attach some roles - everything works fine. However, when I delete a user (`User::destroy(2)`) the rows for that user in the `role_user` table do not get deleted, which is causing redundant rows.

What am I doing wrong?

- MySQL + InnoDB

EDIT: Grabbing the model and applying `->delete();` also has the same effect.

Comment: Have you relationships created in MySQL? Check your table structure in software like PHPMyAdmin. Also try to remove `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: I have PHPMyAdmin installed - where do I view the relationships? Will have a gander.

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/phpmyadmin_relation_view-600x443.png This may help

Comment: Nope nothing there. Confusing... no errors are thrown during migrations.

Comment: So there isn't any relationship marked in PHPMyAdmin? Something must be wrong with schema in this case. I would turn logging queries on and check them during migration.

Comment: Okay, I manually set `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` and now it's working, even though it says "InnoDB" under the "type" column in the DB. Weird.

Comment: Check once again queries. There will be problem described. If it's is a bug with table engine please report it on laravel github. Good luck with your application.

Comment: I've found this issue, and the comment above about setting the table engine manually fixed the issue. I have filed a bug: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8730

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting when trying to create this table. This fix has worked for me.

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

I have filed a bug under: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8730

Comment: This problem occurs most probably because the default table engine in your MySQL instance is set to MyISAM which doesn't support foreign keys. Trying to work with foreign keys on a MyISAM table would definitely not be a bug in Laravel. Although it would be nice if the Schema Builder could automatically set the engine to InnoDB if foreign keys are used.

Comment: Make sure you add it to all migrations or it would not work.

Comment: Who still uses MyISAM though :)

Answer (score 13):

It is established by Jake's answer that you have set default engine to InnoDB

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Instead of doing it in each migration file, You can do so in `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

Comment: To add to Shreyansh's answer this is faster but you need to restart your localhost:8000 then run  `php artisan migrate:fresh`   Of course back up your data first.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old issue, but recently (on Laravel 8) I had the same problem even when using InnoDB.

I solved it by using the constrained() option on the relationship. Without the "constrained" parameter, the migration won't create the actual relationship on the database.

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the MySQL config. **my.ini** may still have `default-storage-engine=MYISAM`. Set to `default-storage-engine=InnoDB` and you should avoid the trouble of adding this fix to each migration.

Comment: After changing `my.ini` on local dev machine under Windows & WAMP do not forget to restart the WAMP services (left-click on taskbar icon and select **Restart All Services**)

Answer (score 3):

For someone that's here and using `SoftDeletes` on their models; `onDelete('cascade')` functionality is lost when using SoftDeletes. Options you could use in such a case are:

1. Using [dyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes) package to handle this for you.
2. Using [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) to trigger an event that the parent has been deleted and handle the deletion of the child rows yourself.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-soft-delete-cascade Here is an example well explained.

Answer (score 0):

even after changing the engine to `InnoDB` in Config->Database
it does not work

and the solution for that is to change the migration

From

`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->BigIncrements('id');`

To

`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');`

Comment: I really don't think that changing `BigIncrements` to `increments` is a desired answer.

The bigInteger method creates a `BIGINT` equivalent column And The `increments` method creates an auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER equivalent column as a primary key.