# Delete all posts related to a user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

this is my posts table

```
   public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
                $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
                $table->integer('photo_id')->default(0)->unsigned()->index();
                $table->string('title');
                $table->text('body');
                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');


            });
        }
```

this is my users table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('photo_id')->index()->default(0);
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

these are the relations

```
 public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Delete code of the user

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        if($user->photo_id !== 0) {
            unlink(public_path() . $user->photo->path);
        }


        $user->delete();

        Session::flash('deleted_user', 'The user has been deleted.');

        return redirect('/admin/users');
    }
```

Delete code of the post

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        if($post->photo_id !== 0) {
            unlink(public_path() . $post->photo->path);
        }


        $post->delete();

        return redirect('/admin/posts');

    }
```

I am trying to delete all the posts related to a user when I delete a user.
For that, I am using foreign reference constraint in posts table as shown above
But it is not working when I delete the user. The posts are still there.
I dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: what is your delete code ?

Comment: See above I added it in the question

Comment: Take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30225134/5458806

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using and what version of MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem occurs most probably because the default table engine in your MySQL instance is set to MyISAM which doesn't support foreign keys. Trying to work with foreign keys on a MyISAM table would definitely not be a bug in Laravel. Although it would be nice if the Schema Builder could automatically set the engine to InnoDB if foreign keys are used.

so, use this line in your schema

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

or alter the table with

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

May be help you.

Comment: But Whats the difference between InnoDB and MyISAM and how would it affect my application

Comment: Check: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-config-wizard-database-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Create you custom method like `function destroyAllByUser()`

and put the code like

```
DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', '=', 1)->delete();
```

I hope it may help

Comment: Yes, I could do this but it would be better if we could use what Laravel provides us already.

Answer (score 0):

Delete user;

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    if($user->photo_id !== 0) {
        unlink(public_path() . $user->photo->path);
    }

    $user->posts->delete();

    $user->delete();

    Session::flash('deleted_user', 'The user has been deleted.');

    return redirect('/admin/users');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A alternative way to solve that is to configure database.php file under laravel-project\config folder to work on InnoDB engine.

```
'mysql' => [
   ...

   'engine' => 'InnoDB'
 ]
```

Now you don't need to worry when you using foreign keys...
REMEMBER - If you didn't configured this before you create your tables you should remigrate again.