# Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have two table with relation, defined in model and migration but when I delete the parent data the child do not delete automatically

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Friendable;
    use HasApiTokens;

    public function userstatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserStatus::class);
    }
}
```

**UserStatus model**

```
class UserStatus extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToOne(User::class);
    }

}
```

**User migration**:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first');
            $table->string('last');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('question');
            $table->string('answer');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('verified')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**UserStatus migration**:

```
class CreateUserStatusesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('status')->default('InActive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('userstatuses');
    }
}
```

and I also tried using old ways on migration not working. There are a lot of relations in user and I can't delete them one by one each time so it needs to delete automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897300/laravel-foreign-key-ondeletecascade-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your migration:

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

See also: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8730

Answer (score 0):

Change the foreign key reference.

```
class CreateUserStatusesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('status')->default('InActive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('userstatuses');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
             $table->engine = "InnoDB";
             $table->interger('user_id')->unsigned();  
             $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('status')->default('InActive');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```